# Segfault on copy constructor for string

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, copy-constructor

I'm getting a segfault on a line where I'm creating a c++ string with the copy constructor. I've looked at some of the similar issues, but they're all due to passing in a bad c++ string object. I'm just passing in a raw string, so I'm not sure what my issue is. I'll paste the relevant snippets of code (it's taken from several different files, so it might look a bit jumbled). The segfault occurs in the 4th line of the default constructor for the Species class.

```
Species::Species(string _type) {
    program_length = 0;
    cout << _type << " 1\n";
    cout << type << " 2\n";
    type = string(_type);
}

Grid::Grid(int _width, int _height) {
    *wall = Species("wall");
    *empty = Species("empty");
    turn_number = 0;
    width = _width;
    height = _height;
    for(int a= 0; a < 100; a++)
        for(int b = 0; b< 100; b++) {
            Creature empty_creature = Creature(*empty,a,b,NORTH,this);
            (Grid::map)[a][b] = empty_creature;
        }
}

int main() {
    Grid world = Grid(8,8);
}

class Grid {
protected:
    Creature map[100][100];
    int width,height;
    int turn_number;
    Species *empty;
    Species *wall;
public:
    Grid();
    Grid(int _width, int _height);
    void addCreature(Species &_species, int x, int y, Direction orientation);
    void addWall(int x, int y);
    void takeTurn();
    void infect(int x, int y, Direction orientation, Species &_species);
    void hop(int x, int y, Direction orientation);
    bool ifWall(int x, int y, Direction orientation);
    bool ifEnemy(int x, int y, Direction orientation, Species &_species);
    bool ifEmpty(int x, int y, Direction orientation);
    void print();
};

class Species {
    protected:
    int program_length;
    string program[100];
    string type;
    public:
    species(string _type);
    void addInstruction(string instruction);
    bool isWall();
    bool isEmpty();
    bool isEnemy(Species _enemy);
    string instructionAt(int index);
    string getType();
};
```

Here's my updated code after I removed pointers from wall and empty. I'm now getting a strange error ("error: field wall is not a member of Grid"):

```
Grid::Grid(int _width, int _height) {
    (Grid::wall) = Species("wall");
        (Grid::empty) = Species("empty");
        cout << (*wall).getType() << "\n";
        turn_number = 0;
        width = _width;
        height = _height;
        for(int a= 0; a < 100; a++)
            for(int b = 0; b< 100; b++) {
                Creature empty_creature = Creature(Grid::empty,a,b,NORTH,this);
                (Grid::map)[a][b] = empty_creature;
            }
}

class Grid {
protected:
    Creature map[100][100];
    int width,height;
    int turn_number;
    Species empty;
    Species wall;
public:
    Grid();
    Grid(int _width, int _height);
    void addCreature(Species &_species, int x, int y, Direction orientation);
    void addWall(int x, int y);
    void takeTurn();
    void infect(int x, int y, Direction orientation, Species &_species);
    void hop(int x, int y, Direction orientation);
    bool ifWall(int x, int y, Direction orientation);
    bool ifEnemy(int x, int y, Direction orientation, Species &_species);
    bool ifEmpty(int x, int y, Direction orientation);
    void print();
};
```

Comment: In you class definition, species is written lowercase, C++ is case sensitive. (posted as comment this time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause of the problem is the `Species` pointer data members that you are de-referencing without initializing:

```
Grid::Grid(int _width, int _height) {
  *wall = Species("wall");  // wall not initialized. What does it point to?
  *empty = Species("empty"); // likewise for empty
```

Which begs the question: do you need them to be pointers anyway? (hint: most likely not)

When not using pointers, you could easily initialize the data members in the constructor's initialization list:

```
Grid::Grid(int _width, int _height) 
: width(_width), height(_height), turn_number(0), wall("wall"), empty("empty") 
{ 
  ....
}
```

Comment: I changed it to not use pointers and now I'm getting a weirder error: "error: field wall is not a member of Grid". I'll update my code for you in my original post

Comment: @user2756569 I added an example. I suggest you read an introductory C++ book.

Comment: I don't understand how moving the initialization of wall and empty to the initialization list would fix the current error. The compiler still tells me wall/empty are not members of grid after the change you suggested, when they clearly are.

Comment: @user2756569 You should try to come up with a *small* example that illustrates and reproduces the problem you see and post it as a separate question. There must be another error somewhere, which will be easier to see with smaller code.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the help ^_^